# Need Functionality like lexis audio editor for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, audio-recording

I need functionality like lexis audio editor for my android app. Can someone suggest me something??
Features I require are append, merge, insert audio in between or overlap recording.

Comment: I can suggest you to use Google.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go to some tutorial website ,because this is not a tutorial website. If you get any errors in building that app .